# Laptop Internal Keyboard and Touchpad Working in Windows but not Linux

Tags: windows, keyboard, touchpad

I have a HP Spectre x360 (model number:13t-ac000) that was originally running Windows before I put Ubuntu 18.10 on it about 9 months. Everything was working fine until last week when the internal touchpad and keyboard stopped working.

So far I've discovered that the touchpad and keyboard work in the bios and Windows but not on Ubuntu 18.10, Ubuntu 19.04, Ubuntu 16.04, or Arch Linux.

I've reinstalled the operating system multiple times. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There are many HP Spectre x360 https://store.hp.com/us/en/mdp/laptops/spectre-x360-211501--1#!&tab=vao laptops. Would you please be so kind as to flip it over, find the model number on the same sticker or plate as the serial number? Please click [edit] and add it to your original question; please do not use Add Comment, but instead use [edit].